# Adding Attributes to Test Kitchen

Tags: yaml, chef-infra, test-kitchen

I'm trying to override attributes in the `java` cookbook with [test-kitchen](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen).

When I try run `kitchen converge default-centos-64`, a bad YAML error shows up.

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant
  customize:
    memory: 1024
    cpuexecutioncap: 50

provisioner:
  name: chef_solo

platforms:
  - name: centos-6.4

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list: 
      - recipe[java::default]
      - recipe[maven::default]
    attributes: {
                  java.install_flavor: "oracle",
                  java.jdk_version: "7"
                }
```

I pasted the above into http://yamllint.com/. When I hit "Go," it removes all lines beginning at "attributes", and then shows a Green "Valid YAML".

Comment: Supply the attributes also as yaml, not as json.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Do you want to post the answer for credit?

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm glad that it helped. While searching for any documentation I am wondering about the example in the github wiki.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Attributes are supplied as normal yaml content:

```
suites:
  - name: default
    run_list: 
      - recipe[java::default]
      - recipe[maven::default]
    attributes:
       java:
         install_flavor: "oracle",
         jdk_version: "7"
```

The [Getting Started](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/wiki/Getting-Started) shows a syntax similar to yours:

```
suites:
  - name: default
    run_list: 
      - recipe[java::default]
      - recipe[maven::default]
    attributes: { 'java': { 'install_flavor': 'oracle' } }
```

Comment: so the `{}` braces aren't needed? I've been using them successfully. example: `attributes: { 'java': { 'install_flavor': 'oracle' } }`

Comment: I'm using the complete yaml style [here](https://github.com/TYPO3-cookbooks/gerrit/blob/77f05d33aefb93de670796e81c7b3322264c22a4/.kitchen.yml#L30-33), but it seems that it doesn't matter, if it is completely yaml or the whole attributes a valid json hash (I would say that yours isn't a valid json style). I'm updating my answer.

Comment: It's easy to confuse the new ruby hash notation with json hash notation.

This is a ruby hash with a symbol called key mapped to a string "value": `{ key: "value" }`. And this is a json hash corresponding
`{ "key": "value" }`. It was easier to spot ruby hashes prior to ruby 2.0 they were all like this `{ :key => "value" }`