# Adding Complex Attributes to Test Kitchen

Tags: chef-infra, yaml, test-kitchen

I have the following chef attribute that i'm trying to convert to YAML for test-kitchen:

```
default['attr1']['attr2'] = {
    "setting1" => {
        "key1" => "value1",
        "key2" => "value2",
        "key3" => false
    },
};
```

What would this look like in YAML so test-kitchen will override it properly?  I want to override the false value to true for specific test-kitchen drivers.

There is a similar SO question: [Adding Attributes to Test Kitchen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224384/adding-attributes-to-test-kitchen) but the attribute i'm trying to convert is more complicated (i.e the value is not a simple string).

Answer (score 2):

Should be

```
attr1:
  attr2:
    setting1:
      key1: value1
      key2: value2
      key3: false
```

Answer (score 1):

My best idea, use irb:

```
irb(main):001:0> h={
irb(main):002:1*     "setting1" => {
irb(main):003:2*         "key1" => "value1",
irb(main):004:2*         "key2" => "value2",
irb(main):005:2*         "key3" => false
irb(main):006:2>     },
irb(main):007:1* }
=> {"setting1"=>{"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2", "key3"=>false}}

irb(main):010:0> require 'yaml'
=> true

irb(main):011:0> h.to_yaml
=> "---\nsetting1:\n  key1: value1\n  key2: value2\n  key3: false\n"
```

Disclaimer: I'm not using test-kitchen nor yaml usually, so it may or may not work.